# IIS 6 Default 404 page use relative 'File' instead of 'URL'

Tags: iis-6

I've got an IIS6 server that is returning 200 when I have my custom 404 page set (Set to be URL /404.htm).

Reading up on it, it seems that if I use the 'file' option instead, it will return an actual 404 status code.

However, I want to be able to set this for all websites on my server (a few hundred), so I want to be able to use a relative path.

When using IIS Manager, it only allows me to pick an absolute path.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's IIS, can you simply drop a file in the root of each website? (would probably be easy with a batch file).

This file would be a `web.config` file (used in ASP.NET)

The code in the web.config would look like this.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
            <error statusCode="404" redirect="http://localhost/404.htm" />
        </customErrors>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Then you make another website in IIS that hosts your `404.htm` file, and have it executed at `localhost`

---

Alternatively you can create a `404.aspx` file and wire it up as your 404 error page (instead of the `404.htm`). This file would look something like this.

```
<%@ Page language="c#" %>
<html>
<head>
   <script language="CS" runat="server">
      void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
      {
          // here were actually telling the browser that the page is 404 and not 200
          Response.Status = "404 Not Found";
          Response.StatusCode = 404;
      } 
   </script>
   <title>404: Whoops, we lost your file.</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>404</h1>
    <div>Oops, the resource you are looking for is unavailable</div>
</body>
</html>
```